# Adding menu listener for Paste option in SWT Browser

Tags: eclipse, browser, swt, contextmenu, listener

I have a org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser instance created in a composite. I would like to know when some content is pasted in the browser using the (platform specific) right click context menu and selecting the paste option.

In the menuDetected() of MenuDetectListener, I get a notification when the context menu is detected in the browser.

How can I know if the Paste option is selected from the context menu?

Regards,
Noopur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No you can't** access the selected context menu item. There is no direct provision for that. At least not in eclipse 3.7. Although, you could try different combinations of events for determining the menu item. For example, in windows the internet explorer populates the status bar with `'inserts the clipboard...'` when your mouse pointer hovers over the `Paste` menu item, you can capture this using `StatusTextListener` event.

***`Note:`*** The hack is not an elegant solution, even if you get it working, there is still some possibility that it may break with new or older releases of SWT or in fact its behavior may vary with operating systems !!